# Need snow shield ideas for photo eye case

Tags: building

We have two automatic bay doors at our carwash. These doors are operated (open, close) by photoeyes. When installed they were installed diagonally to each other instead of horizontally. One of the eyes on both exit doors was installed pretty much right on the ground in metal square cases. Problem is that when it snows because one is so close to the ground snow covers the eye and the door opens. I've got to work and the doors are open and things are a little froze. I'm looking for ideas on how to build something around it to block it from being covered. I've thought about raising it a bit from the ground, but I'd have to raise the other one as well. I've got a couple pictures attached. Let me know if anymore are needed. Thanks[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Is it the snow right on the eye, or would snow mid-driveway also trigger it to open.  Do you need to keep the entire path of the beam clear?

Comment: Snow gathers right on the eye. The beam is fine, but when the eye gets covered it breaks the beam and causes the door to remain open. Its the safety feature. I can set the doors to manual but if that beam is broke that door opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place the lower eye in a larger clear or windowed box with the window vertical or overhanging slightly.

[image]

Comment: Good idea, but the angle of the box would still allow snow to sit. What do u mean on the last part? Giving it a bit of overhang above the eye?

Comment: have the eye look out the side of the box

Comment: I see what u mean by angling the cover. But I don't know what u mean by having the eye look out the side of the box.

Comment: the top of the box will accumulate snow, the side should be snow-free

Comment: What about engineering a tube that would hold the eye? Think It'd be a waste of time?

Comment: need to keep snow from in front to the lens.  could do a slant-end tube like cannoli but clear boxes are available off the shelf.

Comment: I like the tube concept. Its quick but you get the right angle of snow or rain and it might wear the lense out faster.

Comment: If you are in a car wash you probably have PVC pipe around.  I think I see some in your picture.  See if that works.